# Apply formula to the entire column

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

I'm changing all the zip codes from Column A into Column B with the formula:

```
=TEXT(A1,"00000")
```

Like this:

[image]

I want every cell in Column B to be transformed using the formula above. But I have over 40,000 rows, so it is not feasible to drag the formula down to apply it to the entire Column B because it takes so long.

Are there any alternatives to dragging?

Comment: Also might be useful to some: To ignore the cells that do not have the formula's required data and leave them blank use an if statement like this: `=IF(somecell<>"",yourformula,"")`.

Answer (score 171):

It looks like some of the other answers have become outdated, but for me this worked:

1. Click on the cell with the text/formula to copy
2. Shift+Click on the last cell to copy to
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> on Mac.)

(Note that this replaces text if the destination cells aren't empty)

Comment: Only works on one column at a time, but works well.  If you wanna get this done quickly for a lot of stuff, `Ctrl+Shift+Down` will select all the way to the bottom of the current column, `Ctrl+Enter` like you said, then `Up, Right, [Down]` (last one won't be needed if you're on row 1) to get to the next column.

Answer (score 132):

I think it's a more recent feature, but...

Double clicking the square on the bottom right of the highlighted cell copies the formula of the highlighted cell.

Comment: This is the correct answer to the question. Double clicking on "drag indicator" (bottom right corner) will copy the formula to all cells. Make sure you CLEAR your column data first and only apply your formula to one. The above answer with "ArrayFormula" seems to be able to apply a many cells to one formula, which is not what OP wanted.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. It works fine for me but I prefer using the ArrayFormula function, simply because unlike your method which basically would copy the exact same formula down to every cell, ArrayFormula will be more dynamic and can be programmed more easily.

Comment: @ThanasisKapelonis, you do not need to clear data, You just double click on the drag indicator and it applies the formula to all subsequent rows where data in each placeholder is available in corresponding columns for that row. It will stop where the data is missing. as shown by Brett Sutton

Comment: I have too much data to do this answer, it fails and I have to reload the page.

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.

Comment: This doubleclick only seems to work when there is data in the column immediately beside the one you're filling... if there's e.g. an empty "spacer" column in between, it just fails, silently.

Comment: While *technically* correct, this can be tedious if you have a large number of rows. Also, you have to repeat the process every time you change the formula. Check the answer by @pnuts (currently the third answer, but I hope it will get more upvotes). I just tried that and it works like magic!

Comment: I tried the double click trick for a `VLOOKUP` formula but didn't get it to work as it returned `#N/A`. However when I wrap the `VLOOKUP` in `IFNA(VLOOKUP(…), "Not found")` if does work. This does not work for empty cells though.

Comment: For me, this only worked if the cell was not selected.

Answer (score 69):

I think you are in luck. Please try entering in B1:

```
=text(A1:A,"00000")
```

(very similar!) but before hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This is a shortcut for wrapping the formula with `ArrayFormula()`:

```
=ArrayFormula(text(A1:A,"00000"))
```

Comment: @pnuts maybe this has changed in the last year, but ArrayFormula does not extend the formula down Column B as the image from the OP. For me, It simply fills the value of the selected cell.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Worked really well for me. I think that one thing that folks may be missing is the B1:B part which I struggled with myself for a few second. You have to replace your single column, say B1 with an array of columns B1:B in your formula, in order for it to function. By far, this is the best method and the most dynamic.

Comment: This worked for me as well. Thanks for the clarifications in the comments. An additional thing that tripped me up was that the cells below must all be empty. I guess I thought they would just be overwritten.

Comment: If it doesn't work look at your formula check the cell format. We usually would write `=text(A1,"00000")` (just `A1`) but for the array formula you need to write it as `=text(A1:A,"00000")` (`A1:A`). That makes the difference between working and not working.

Answer (score 38):

This worked for me:

- Input the `formula` in the first cell.
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Click on the first cell and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>down_arrow</kbd>. This will select the last cell in the column used on the worksheet.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>. This will fill copy the formula in the remaining cells.

Comment: And if you use mac, replace `Shift` with `Command`.

Answer (score 18):

This is for those who want to ***overwrite*** the column cells quickly (without cutting and copying). This is the same as double-clicking the cell box but unlike double-clicking, it still works after the first try.

1. Select the column **cell** you would like to copy downwards
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⇓</kbd> to select the cells below
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to copy the contents of the first cell into the cells below

**BONUS:**

The shortcut for going to the bottom-most content (to double-check the copy) is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⇓</kbd>. To go back up you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>⇑</kbd> but if your top rows are frozen you'll also have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> a few times.

Comment: Replace `Ctrl` with `Cmd` in macOs and it would still work, thank you

Answer (score 13):

For Mac:

Click on the first cell having the formula and press Ctrl + Shift + down_arrow. This will select the last cell in the column used on the worksheet.

---

#### `Command + D`

---

**(don't use ctrl)**. This will fill the formula in the remaining cells.

Answer (score 10):

**Let's say** you want to substitute something in an array of string and **you don't want to perform the copy-paste on your entire sheet**.

Let's take this as an example:

- String array in column "A": {apple, banana, orange, ..., avocado}
- You want to substitute the char of "a" to "x" to have: {xpple, bxnxnx,
  orxnge, ..., xvocado}

To apply this formula on the entire column (array) in a clean an elegant way, you can do:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUE(A:A, "a", "x"))
```

It works for 2D-arrays as well, let's say:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUE(A2:D83, "a", "x"))
```

Answer (score 10):

Found another solution:

- Apply the formula to the first 3 or 4 cells of the column
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> the formula in one of the last rows (if you copy the first line it won't work)
- Click on the column header to select the whole column
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to paste it in all cells bellow

Comment: This seems to work more reliably than double-clicking for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Just so I don't lose my answer that works:

1. Select the cell to copy
2. Select the final cell in the column
3. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

Comment: Nice! Note: it should be shift-click for step 2.

Answer (score 8):

Reading the answers here did not quite work for me, but a combination did. Here are my steps (Windows, Chrome):

- Select the cell with the formula you want to apply to the column (for the whole column, ensure this is the top cell)
- Ctrl + Shift + Down (selects all below cells)
- Ctrl + D (apply formula)

Done!

Based on:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/61112723/3200858
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/51411774/3200858

Answer (score 5):

You can use Ctrl+Shift+Down+D to add the formula to every cell in the column as well.

Simply click/highlight the cell with the equation/formula you want to copy and then hold down Ctrl+Shift+Down+D and your formula will be added to each cell.

Answer (score 3):

The exact formula is:

```
=ArrayFormula(text(A1:A,"00000"))
```

[ArrayFormula](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/array-formula-intro/) works on multiple rows (in the above example, every row), and results are placed in the cell with the formula and the cells below it in the same column. It looks as if the same formula was copied into all those rows.

If any of the cells in that column are not empty, they won't get overwritten. Instead, you will get an error message.

To save yourself typing, you can use the trick from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24941209/apply-formula-to-the-entire-column/24966144#24966144) above by [pnuts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1505120/pnuts):

Type: `=text(A1:A,"00000")` and then hit the following key combination:

- On windows: `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`
- On a MAC: `Command`+`Shift`+`Enter`

This will convert the formula to *ArrayFormula*.

After hitting the key combination, you need to hit Enter, to actually apply the converted formula.

If your sheet contains header row(s), and you want to apply formula from (for example) row 5 on, you would use =text(A5:A,"00000") instead.

This answer includes information from [pnuts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1505120/pnuts)'s answer and [LOAS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/193050/loas)'s comment.

Answer (score 1):

### Lambda Solution

Using the new [`LAMBDA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en-CA) and [`MAP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568985) functions, this is now doable without an `ArrayFormula` or having to drag anything.

```
=MAP(A2:A6, LAMBDA(value, TEXT(value, "00000")))
```

- `LAMBDA` defines a function. `value` is the parameter, which we can use in the formula expression.
- `MAP` applies the `LAMBDA` to each value in the given range. This also works on 2D ranges.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear when you us the drag indicator it will only copy the cell values down the column whilst there is a value in the adjacent cell in a given row.
As soon as the drag operation sees an adjacent cell that is blank it will stop copying the formula down.

.e.g

```
1,a,b
2,a
3,
4,a
```

If the above is a spreadsheet then using the double click drag indicator on the 'b' cell will fill row 2 but not row three or four.

Comment: If you are trying to apply the formula to rows in a filtered set in Excel by using the "Double click the drag indicator", it will stop every time the serial number of the row jumps, i.e  row no. 1, 2, 3 if they appear in order will get applied with the formula, however if row no. 5 appears after row no. 3 (Due to filtering) then row no. 5 will not get the formula appled. In that case you have to copy from the cell in row no. 3 and paste it in row no. 5 and then use the same double click.   Yeah, excel Sucks.

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Another easiest and simplest way is as in my file rows were above 16000, which is pretty huge number. So steps which helped me are:


**1.** Select the cell in which formula is written.
**2.** Then go to **NameBox**(it is the box which tells about active cell). Here in my case it was the cell where was formula was written(i.e P2).
**3.** Then in that cell type your **active cell number:your last row**.For example **last row of my column was 16745** and **formula was written in P2**.
So write **P2:P16745**,
**4.** Press Enter in Name Box and bingo your whole area of column till last row is selected.
**5.** Now press **Ctrl+D**(Windows)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(TEXT(A2:A; "00000"))
```

advantages: short, works, smells nice

to map out empty cells you can do:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A="";;TEXT(A2:A; "00000")))
```

Comment: note that INDEX will output the formatted date as datevalue

Answer (score -2):

You may fill the column by double-clicking on the bottom right hand corner of the cell which you want to copy from (the point on the box that you would otherwise drag) and it will be applied to whole column.

NB: This doesn't work if you have the filter applied, nor if there is already something already in the cells below.

Comment: This is correct, however, you must make sure that no data is in the cells beneath the cell containing your formula.

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.