# With 3 columns how would I apply a formula to the first 2 and display the result in the 3rd?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, array-formulas

In Google Sheets I want to get the sum of the first 2 columns and display that result in the 3rd column all the way down. Like this:

[image]

I'm hoping for a solution that does this in one step. As I have *many* rows.

**Edit:** I am aware of this question: [Apply formula to the entire column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24941209/apply-formula-to-the-entire-column) and it appears to only cover part of what I am asking.

Comment: @pnuts ...Oh. Answer my question so I can accept?

Comment: Yes. And thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=arrayformula(if(A2:A<>"",ADD(A2:A,B2:B),""))
```